# How do I disable the on/off button on my notebook?

Tags: shutdown

I need to disable the power button of my laptop. It happens that sometimes I press it by mistake and my work goes.

It'd be optimal for me to make this button inoffensive, e.g. nothing happens pressing it.

How I do that in Ubuntu 12.04?

Actually if I press the button this popup appears:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run the following commands in Terminal to disable the power button:

```
sudo sed -i 's/action=/#action=/g' /etc/acpi/events/powerbtn
sudo gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power nothing
```

> Note: this will result in `syslog` logging the following message: `skipping incomplete file /etc/acpi/events/powerbtn`.

Reboot your computer, and try hitting the power button!

Voilà :)

*<sub>Click [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2020630) for a user's detailed analysis of the underlying mechanisms that are triggered when someone hits the power button.</sub>*

Comment: For a moment I was impressed! Then I tried and did the reboot, but the shutdown popup keep showing (see my updated question).

Comment: @Guandalino Try again with my edit.

Comment: Still nothing. I'll gladly accept any further suggestion!

Comment: @Guandalino So it worked after all?

Comment: Yes! I followed the thread on Ubuntu forum post by post and it did the trick. PS: I'm not sure it's safe commenting the `action` line in `/etc/acpi/events/powerbtn`. It results in this syslog message: `skipping incomplete file /etc/acpi/events/powerbtn`. Maybe say that in your answer. I leaved it uncommented.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it unsafe.. I'll note it, though. Glad your issue is fixed!

Comment: Kudos to Ubuntu developers, but I'd say them that there should be a GUI for such things.