# Disable Poweroff Button and poweroff via terminal in 22.04

Tags: shutdown, reboot

i want to remove or disable the poweroff button for all users. And also the poweroff via terminal if possible. Or request the password to prevent an accidental poweroff.
Is there an option for that?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/193770/how-do-i-disable-the-on-off-button-on-my-notebook?rq=1 for your first request, it's old but might still work

Comment: I already tried that. Since its a VM that doesnt work unfortunately.

Comment: what is a power button on a vm? or do you mean like in the system dashboard or something?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248002/edit-ubuntu-20-04-power-off-logout-menu https://askubuntu.com/questions/1318113/how-to-disable-the-logout-button-while-keeping-the-possibility-to-power-off?rq=1 <- for disabling the power off button, https://askubuntu.com/questions/789058/how-to-make-sbin-shutdown-sbin-reboot-etc-require-sudo-again-in-16-04?rq=1 <- for requiring sudo for shutdown

Comment: Yes, i mean the reboot and shut down button in the dashboard (top right corner)